# how do you mark/highlight text/letters, just like in word or a PDF-file but now in PHP and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, highlight, highlighting

how do you mark text/letters, just like in word or a PDF-file?

I'm trying to create an exercise where people have to mark a word or some characters. 

e.g.

```
<h3>find the number in this sentence</h3>
<p>I like the movie Moneyball</p>
```

***Solution:***

`<h3>find the number in this sentence</h3>` `I like the movie M`**one**`yball`

- for each exercise, you know the question, the sentence and the answer.
- and the thing that I want is, the value of the words you've selected
- - it would be nice, if you select a word or some letters (depending when you loose the mousebutton), than the background color changes into green (and the next time, the previous mark will be dissapear and starts over...

I thought on jquery --> .selectet() but there is so les information and I don't have any experience with that.

All help is welcome,

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

you can use this [jQuery Selectable](https://github.com/jairajs89/jquery-selectable/blob/master/jquery-selectable.js) plugin

Answer (score 0):

I personally would wrap the text you want to highlight in a span tag and style the background color of the span:

```
Your text and the <span class="highlight">text you want to highlight</span>
```

To clarify ... I would pre-wrap the "correct" areas with the span and attach a click event so you can detect when it is selected. That way you can easily detect when they click in the correct location and work from there.

If you want to do it a different way you could style an input element so it looks like regular text and then use the selection information from that. You should be able to get the value string into memory and use the selection info to substring out the part they have selected.

Comment: The poster is asking how to get the value of the selected word, in jQuery; not 'how to highlight the word'.

Answer (score 0):

I took this as a personal challenge since I can imagine a lot of uses. Here is a [simple gist that splits all the words into dom elements](https://gist.github.com/2493590) and keeps track of words before and after it.